# Button click inside Modal pop is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, modal-dialog

I have a div, inside which I have a `FileUpload` and `Button Click`. The div is a pop up section. See the HTML

```
<div id="modal_dialog" style="display: none;">
                    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload" CausesValidation="false" OnClick="btnUpload_Click" CssClass="btn btn-danger" />
                </div>
                <asp:Button ID="btnModalPopup" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-danger" Text="Upload Excel" />
```

But whenever I open the popup and upload the file and click the submit button. The button does not works.

See the Javascript for calling the pop up:

```
$("[id*=mainContent_btnModalPopup]").live("click", function () {
        $("#modal_dialog").dialog({
            title: "Upload Sheet",
            buttons: {
                Close: function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            },
            modal: true
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: If you remove your 'display:none' on your modal_dialog div, does your upload button works well (without using your modal) ?

Comment: @RobinLeboeuf: Yes it works perfectly without `modal`. But currently my client requires that in pop up.

Comment: Ok it was just to check if the problem really came from modal or not. Can you provide a fiddle ?

Comment: @RobinLeboeuf: In fiddle what do you want. I mean only the pop up part or the full aspx page ?

Comment: I guess the rendered html of the popup is enough

Comment: @RobinLeboeuf: Since it is an aspx control, i guess the control won't be visible. See the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/m3z9cbgr/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72029/discussion-between-robin-leboeuf-and-nadeem-khan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code

```
$(function () {
        $("[id*=btnModalPopup]").live("click", function () {
            $("#modal_dialog").dialog({
                title: "Upload Sheet",
                buttons: {
                    Close: function () {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    },
                },
                open: function (type, data) { $(this).parent().appendTo("form"); },
                modal: true
            });
            return false;
        });
    })


<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="div1" style="display: none">
        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Upload" CausesValidation="false" OnClick="btnUpload_Click" />
    </div>
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Show Modal Popup" />

</form>

 protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
            {
                string fileName = FileUpload1.FileName;

                FileUpload1.SaveAs("~/Images/" + fileName);
            }
        }
```

Comment: What does `open: function (type, data) { $(this).parent().appendTo("form"); }` do here. ??

Comment: http://webmisterradixlecti.blogspot.in/2013/04/aspnet-postback-in-jquery-ui-modal.html

Comment: Got it now, thanks Lokesh it is working perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

In this case i usually make these buttons hidden and invoke them from the UIDialog buttons:

First of all add two class to your buttons:

```
            <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload" CausesValidation="false" OnClick="btnUpload_Click" CssClass="btn btn-danger upLoadClass" />
        </div>
        <asp:Button ID="btnModalPopup" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-danger upLoadExcelClass" Text="Upload Excel" />
```

then in your jquery function:

```
$("#modal_dialog").dialog({
    title: "Upload Sheet",
    buttons: {
        Upload: function () {
            $(this).find('.upLoadClass').click();
            $(this).dialog('close');
        },
        UploadExcel: function () {
            $(this).find('.upLoadExcelClass').click();
            $(this).dialog('close');
        },
        Close: function () {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    },
    modal: true
});
```

Comment: @Nadeem Khan, Hope that helps you

Comment: I have submit_click on code behind, how to call that ?

Comment: @NadeemKhan When you call  $(this).find('.upLoadClass').click(); it first execute OnClientClick Method if it exists, Then according to the OnclientClick method; if it returns True ,then your codebhind method will be invoked,

Comment: your jquery code has many `;` expected errors. Please check and update it

Comment: did you add the two new class of your textbox??

Comment: Yes added but Onpage load only i get the pop up. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72039/discussion-between-med-amine-touil-and-nadeem-khan).

Comment: @Nadeem khan. If my answer helped you check it as a helpful answer. Thnx

Comment: Your answer did not worked, the answer of `Lokesh B R` worked :)